# Using a pandas MultiIndex to join two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have two pandas data frames:

`df1`:

```
        column
index1
rec-1   foo
rec-2   bar
rec-3   bar
  :      :
```

`df2`:

```
          test
index2
rec-1-b   baz
rec-2-b   foo
rec-3-b   quux
   :       :
```

along with a MultiIndex object

`multiIndex1`:

```
(rec-1,rec-1-b)
(rec-2,rec-3-b)
:
```

linking the two data frames together. How would I now obtain a data frame that looks like this:

`joined_df`:

```
                  column   test
index1  index2
rec-1   rec-1-b   foo      baz
rec-2   rec-3-b   bar      quux
  :        :       :         :
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('rec-1','rec-1-b'),('rec-2','rec-3-b')])

df = df1.reindex(mux, level=0).join(df2.reindex(mux, level=1))
```

Or:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.reindex(mux, level=0), df2.reindex(mux, level=1)], axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
              column  test
rec-1 rec-1-b    foo   baz
rec-2 rec-3-b    bar  quux
```